# is there any way to test for encrypted string in laravel /PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, aes

Is there any way to check AES-256-CBC encryption?
i m using

```
$encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $cipherMethod, $key,0,$iv);
$decryptedMessage = openssl_decrypt($textToEncrypt, $cipherMethod, $key,0,$iv);
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can use online tools:

[AES Encryption and Decryption Online](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption)